# Protege DataMaster: Table records cannot be shown or imported

Tags: mysql, database, ontology, protege

There are some records in my tables stored in MySQL, and the Protege DataMaster plugin can be successfully connected to the database. Tables can be listed on the left. But when I click any one of them, no table data is shown on the right, i.e. the Preview part.

I'm importing the table **example_table** as "Relational.OWL instances", and I also checked "import table content". All I want is transforming MySQL records into Protege instances. After I clicked "Import",

```
dbs:Database 
dbs:Table 
dbs:Column 
dbs:PrimaryKey 
example_table
```

appeared in the class hierarchy, but in the Individuals tag, no instances were added, i.e. the records in **example_table** were not imported. Anybody has some idea about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I think it's an encoding issue. I'm previously using Chinese for the table name and table contents. However if I change the table name to roman characters the table will work well in DataMaster.